# Why my list doesn't scroll when I scroll down inside the list?

Tags: swiftui

**Why my list doesn't scroll when I scroll down inside the list?**

I know the question sounds silly but I cannot make my list scroll, it SHOULD SCROLL, but doesn't....

My list is very long and I can scroll vertically if my finger scrolls down outside the list but NOT inside (touching the list elements)

I know I can use foreach and dividert to simulate a list but I want to keep using the ondelete etc methods part of the list.

update: the root cause is because I'm using onTapgesture etc, but how can I keep them and still have a list that scrolls?

```
            List {
                ForEach(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { task in
                    Text(task.desc!)
                        .foregroundColor(task.done ? .white : task.today ? .white : .black)
                        .listRowBackground(task.done ? Color.green : task.today ? Color.blue : Color.white)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                            //isPresented.toggle()
                            self.taskToEdit = task
                        }
                        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            Button(role: .cancel) {
                                task.done.toggle()
                                task.today = false
                                task.date_completion = Date()
                                
                                do {try viewContext.save()} catch {
                                    let nsError = error as NSError
                                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                                }
                                
                                print("mark as done")
                            } label: {
                                Label("Done", systemImage: "checkmark")
                            }
                            .tint(.green)
                        }
                        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture()
                            .onEnded { _ in
                                let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                                impactMed.impactOccurred()
                                
                                task.today.toggle()
                                
                                do {try viewContext.save()} catch {
                                    let nsError = error as NSError
                                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
                                }
                                
                                
                                print("Loooong")
                                print(task.today)
                            }
                        )
                    
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                
            }
            //.listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        
            //.listRowInsets(.init(top: 4, leading: 8, bottom: 4, trailing: 8))
            .sheet(item: self.$taskToEdit, content: { taskToEdit in
                itemDetail(taskItem: taskToEdit, textFieldText: taskToEdit.detail ?? "")
            })
        }
```

Comment: Did you try List(fetchRequest, id: \.self) { task in ...?

Comment: Yes, I included a code snippet

Comment: The scroll gesture is disabled/inactive because of tap gesture. 
So tapping in the text will do the tap gesture, and you can scroll outside text. It is better to have smaller area for tap gesture than the size of the list element (I may be wrong but that is how I indeed it)

Comment: Try making making the `Text` be the label of a Button